# how to determine regression slope for each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

i have a dataframe that contains the values of a variable in different years and im going to calculate the slope of the regression for each row of data in a new column.
dataframe contains 4 columns of PCI in 4 years
please advise

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvTu.jpg)
i knew every method, and it didnt

Comment: Please research before asking, and if you believe the Q/A doesn't already exist, make sure to [ask your question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)